# Array of Objects filter angular2

Tags: angular, object, angular-filters, angular-pipe

I am trying to filter through an array of objects. what am I doing wrong.

My Pipe

```
 transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (!args) return value;

    return value.filter(item => this.checkValues(item, args));
  }

  checkValues(item, args) {
    const value = Object.keys(item).map(k => item[k]);

    for (var i in value) {
      return value[i].toString().indexOf(args) > -1;
    }
  }
```

My data will be like

```
data= [
{key:value},
{key1:value2}
]
```

I want to search through the values.

After posting this question I came up with a solution.

My current solution

```
transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (!args) return value;

    return value.filter(item => this.checkValues(item, args));
  }

  checkValues(item, args) {

    const value = Object.keys(item).map(k => item[k]);

    return JSON.stringify(value).indexOf(args) > -1;

  }
```

Is this good. or any recommended method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be acheived by

```
transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (!args) return value;

    return value.filter(item => this.checkValues(item, args));
  }

  checkValues(item, args) {

    const value = Object.keys(item).map(k => item[k]);

    return String(value).indexOf(args) > -1;

  }
```